# IOS 9 - Share Extension Compulsory to get public.file-url

Tags: ios, pdf, ios9, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

**I have an issue in share extension with 2 different scenario in iOS9** (***working fine with iOS8***) --- (***wants to share PDF***):

> **First goto the mail app with PDF attachment mail-**

1. Long press the PDF attachment then select my application from share sheet. It was given me following registeredTypeIdentifiers :

> ```
> registeredTypeIdentifiers: (
>     "public.file-url",
>     "com.adobe.pdf"
> )
> ```

2. Open the PDF from attachment. It was open PDF in UIDocumentInteractionController. UIDocumentInteractionController gives sharing facilities. If i click on the share icon then select my application from share sheet. It was given me following registeredTypeIdentifiers :

> ```
> registeredTypeIdentifiers: (
>     "com.adobe.pdf"
> )
> ```

What should i do to get **"public.file-url"** in the 2nd Scenario.

[See the screen short of 2nd scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaroq.png)

I am using below mention SUBQUERY in plist :

```
SUBQUERY (
          extensionItems,
          $extensionItem,
          SUBQUERY (
                    $extensionItem.attachments,
                    $attachment,

                    (
      ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.file-url" 
      || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
      || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
      || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.png"
      || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg"
      || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg-2000"

       )

                    ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
          ).@count == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

to make customize document type for share extension
write predicates under key NSExtensionActivationRule 
for example:for pdf & image  i made following predicates with maximum amount of document to 1.

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
    <string>SUBQUERY (
        extensionItems,
        $extensionItem,
        SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,

        (
                   ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.png"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg-2000"
        )
        ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
        ).@count == 1</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually gives me same output as **2nd scenario**. :(